# How can I use jQuery global variables within my HTML page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jQuery global variables that I want to just put into my HTML document so that as they're updated via some update function, they'll just update in each spot that the global is referenced automatically. This would save me from writing a function that updates the text.

Basically I want to do this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>
      var globalVariable=  "something";
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>The jQuery global variable is equal to: $(globalVariable)</p>
<body>
</html>
```

Would this even work? Would they update in the page when they are updated in the jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in jQuery, for this functionality it's better to use an MVC or MVVM framework, I would recommend knockout.js (http://knockoutjs.com/), it's very easy to bind variables to DOM elements with it:

```
 <span data-bind="text: myVariable "></span>
```

Comment: You can't do it directly with jQuery, but JsViews + JsRender are designed to allow you to add templates and 2-way data binding to a jQuery app (though they can be used by themselves as well).

Comment: This looks like it's probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant do it . Better way would be to insert your varibale in a place holder like div . assign them class and on every change of variable call the function to replace value in that div with named class.

```
$(".classname").html("changed text")
```

html:

```
   <div class="classname">some value</div>
```

Comment: A better idea is to use data binding like jBind or jsViews.

Answer (score 0):

like this you mean: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/v8v9m/

Hope it fits the needs `:)`

**code**

```
var globalVariable=  "something";

updateme(globalVariable);

$('#foo').click(function(){
        updateme("HULK");

});
function updateme(bar){
 $('#hulk').html(bar);   
}
​
```

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The jQuery global variable is equal to:<laspanle id="hulk"></span></p>
<body>


    <input type="button" value="Update something to hulk" id="foo" />
​
```